# OpenID libraries for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, openid

Are there any OpenID 2.0 libraries for Delphi?

There are none listed in this directory: http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/12995176/Libraries

Comment: Client or server side? For Delphi (FireMonkey) iOS apps, a client implementation could be very interesting.

Comment: I am just looking at client side - that is to say: client to the OpenID provider. My application is a Delphi web app as an ISAPI module hosted on Apache on Win32.

Comment: I think it would be feasible for me to write an OpenID client (designed to work for Delphi 2009 and newer, commercial with source) based on Indy as a prototype and then make it compatible with other HTTP libraries. On the a web application side, I used OpenID authentication already, for a JavaServer Faces app on the Google App Engine. Also for a Delphi web [framework](http://www.habarisoft.com/habari_webcomponents.html) I am working on this could be an interesting extension.

Comment: Mjn: If you are planning to write a commercial library, then great! On the other hand, if you want to write an Free and Open Source library, maybe we could collaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're targeting Windows. I'd suggest you simply link to an external DLL, maybe [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) and don't worry too much about it. You don't need the libraries you use to be in the same language the rest of your program is, as long as you can use functionality embedded in external DLL libraries.